# How many 2021-digit numbers can be formed from {${1,2,3,4,5}$} and is divisible by 3 (possible repetition).

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So i have one approach to the problem. I used pigeon hole theorem to prove that there are at least $[\frac{2021}{5}]+1 = 405$ identical number. And since 405 is divisible by 3 so the sum of those 405 same digit is also divisible by 3 and i only need to solve the problem with $2021 - 405 = 1616$-digit numbers. I continued that until there is less than 3 identical digit (the number of identical digits must be divisible by 3). At that point, the problem can be converted to

> How many 8-digit numbers can be formed from {${1,2,3,4,5}$} and is divisible by 3 (possible repetition).

To solve the above problem, i tried to find all 3x for $5*1 \leq 3x \leq 5*5$ and solve every custom sub-problem. But my solution seems to be too tedious and i wonder if there is a specific formula to solve the first problem. Every idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I also want to know if there is a way to solve this problem

> Share $m$ candy bars to $n$ people such that no one have more than $k$ candy bars.

That sub-problem can help solve my problem.

(Sorry if my English bother you. It is not my first language)

Comment: the title and context do not match.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, i will edit it. What i mean is the question can be rewritten as "How many way to share 3k candy bars (3k > 2021) to 2021 people such that no one have more than 5 candy bars"

Comment: @RAPTOR Do you know generating functions?

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: This question is basically same as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067761/how-many-positive-integers-of-n-digits-chosen-from-the-set-2-3-7-9-are-divisib) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4188700/find-the-number-of-n-digit-positive-integers-divisible-by-3-whose-digits-are-f).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I'll reply more if i have any question :D

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**

This is only an alternative solution to those provided in the comment section

**Solution**

We define vectors $x_{i}$ as a vector containing the number of $i$ digits number that are $0,1,2$ in modulo $3$ respectively. From the problem statement we get:

$$
x_{1}=
\begin{Bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
2
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

An $n+1$ digits number is divisible by $3$ if the first digit is $0$ in modulo $3$ and the last $n$ digits form a number that is $0$ in modulo $3$, the first digit is $1$ in modulo $3$ and the last $n$ digits form a number that is $2$ in modulo $3$, or the first digit is $2$ in modulo $3$ and the last $n$ digits form a number that is $1$ in modulo $3$. Apply similar logic to $n+1$ digits number that is $1$ and $2$ in modulo $3$ to obtain the following recurrence - relations:

$$
x_{n+1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2\\
2 & 1 & 2\\
2 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\times x_{n}
$$

From here, it's easy to show the following is true:

$$
x_{n+1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2\\
2 & 1 & 2\\
2 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{n}
\begin{Bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
2
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

Using eigenvectors and eigenvalues we have:

$$
x_{n+1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
(-1)^{n} & 0 & 0\\
0 & (-1)^{n} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 5^{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3}\\
-\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3}\\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
2
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

The final result is

$$
x_{n} = \frac{1}{3}
\begin{Bmatrix}
5^{n} + 2(-1)^{n}\\
5^{n} - (-1)^{n}\\
5^{n} - (-1)^{n}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

Therefore the number of $n$ digits number with such digits that are divisible by $3$ is given by $\frac{5^{n}+2(-1)^{n}}{3}$